# как правильно получить ключ многомерного массива

Tags: php

есть следующий массив

```
array(2) { 
    ["выбирите Товар"]=> array(5) { 
        ["goods-Postelnoe-bele-Flirt-baz-Ranfors"]=> string(68) "Постельное белье "Флирт" бязь Ранфорс" 
        ["goods-Postelnoe-bele-Bolsie-lilii-baz-Ranfors"]=> string(83) "Постельное белье "Большие лилии" бязь Ранфорс" 
        ["goods-Postelnoe-bele-Vkus-leta-baz-Ranfors"]=> string(75) "Постельное белье "Вкус лета" бязь Ранфорс" 
        ["goods-Postelnoe-bele-Grin"]=> string(42) "Постельное белье "Грин"" 
        ["goods-Postelnoe-bele-Lebedinaa-pesna-baz-Ranfors"]=> string(87) "Постельное белье "Лебединая песня" бязь Ранфорс" } 
    ["выбрать \common\models\Category"]=> array(5) { 
        ["3D"]=> string(13) "3D белье" 
        ["Atlas"]=> string(27) "Атласное белье" 
        ["Atlas-Satin"]=> string(21) "Атлас-Сатин" 
        ["Bannye-polotenca"]=> string(31) "Банные полотенца" 
        ["Bizuteria"]=> string(18) "Бижутерия" } 
    }
```

он храниться в переменной `$allModels`
таким образом я передаю его в функцию
 `$selected=addSelect($allModels)`
вот функция addSelect

```
 function addSelect($models){
       $diff = count($models) - count($models, COUNT_RECURSIVE);//проверяю многомерный ли массив 
    if($diff){
          foreach ($models as $model){
          //здесь я обрабатываю массив код не стал писать, но мне надо получить ключ верхнего массива пытаюсь получить так 
           return key($models);
          }
    }
```

если после этого сделать так 
            var_dump($selected)
получу дважды `"выбирите Товар"` а хотелось бы `"выбирите Товар"` и `"выбрать \common\models\Category"`. Как это можно получить подскажите пожалуйста ?

Comment: Так правильно, вы дважды вызываете тот же код с теми же входными данными, по этому и ответ тот же

Comment: foreach ($models as $key => $model) - где, $key ваш ключ

Comment: @JurijJazdanov точно завтыкал спасибо пишите ответ

Comment: @Sergalas написал))

Comment: @Sergalas, как вы эту функцию вообще используете? Вызываете несколько раз на одном и том же массиве и хотите получить разные ключи из него? Или все ключи разом?

Comment: @Visman все ответ дали спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($models as $key => $model){
    // где $key - выш ключ
}
```